# No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash

```
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-
source /home/Vivado/2014.4/settings64.sh
```

Output :

```
bash: /home/Vivado/2014.4/settings64.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have the `Vivado` file in my home directory. In the above case even though I give the path of my home directory, it is saying `No such file or directory`.

Comment: Please `cd` to the directory in which that file is stored and then give us the output of `pwd`.

Comment: Another thing is that after the `home` directory comes a directory with your username, so instead try: `source /home/akhil/Vivado/2014.4/settings64.sh`

Comment: akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~$ ls
Desktop             Templates               vivado_4896.backup.log
 Videos                  vivado_5138.backup.jou
Documents           Vivado                  vivado_5138.backup.log
Downloads           vivado_2111.backup.jou  vivado.jou
examples.desktop    vivado_2111.backup.log  vivado.log
hs_err_pid1695.log  vivado_4456.backup.jou  vivado_pid4762.str
Music               vivado_4456.backup.log  vivado_pid4896.str
         vivado_4762.backup.jou  xic
Public              vivado_4762.backup.log  zee-bow
SDK                 vivado_4896.backup.jou  zybo_base_system

Comment: perfect (y) there is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the `/home/` will come a directory with your username, so as long as the file is in your home directory this should work:

```
source /home/akhil/Vivado/2014.4/settings64.sh
```

But to avoid confusion in future you may want to use `~` in order to represent the current user's home directory like so:

```
source ~/Vivado/2014.4/settings64.sh
```